# Wordpress: Ajax request logs 400 Bad Request to console

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I keep getting this error:

```
POST http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ VM12565:1
send @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:4
ajax @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:4
(anonymous) @ options-general.php?page=fvc-settings:784
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:3
r.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:3
```

1. In the code below, ajaxPost() is hooked to the admin footer of my
   plugin.
2. On clicking the button selected by jQuery, it should fire the registered post request and return a simple response.

This is not what happens with jQuery.post() or $.ajax(). I tried several things mentioned below in the comments but can't get it working, can anyone tell the issue?

```
function ajaxPost() {
  ?>

  <script>     
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
      $('#previousButton').click(function() {
        var postData = {
          action : 'selectTargetsWithOffset',
          data : {
            offsetMultiplier : 1,
            incrementSize : 10
          },
          success : function(response) {
            console.log(`=====jQuery success=====`);
          }
        };

        var handleResponse = function(response) {
          console.log(response, `=====response=====`);
        };

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, postData, handleResponse);

        // this code also threw a 400 error when 
        // I commented out the above code instead
        // $.ajax({
        //   type: "POST",
        //   url: ajaxurl,
        //   dataType: "json",
        //   data: {
        //     action: "selectTargetsWithOffset",
        //   },
        //   success: function() {
        //     console.log(response, `=====response 
        //       from $.ajax}=====`);
        //   }
        // });

      })

    })
  </script>
  <?php
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'ajaxPost');


function selectTargetsWithOffset() {
  wp_send_json([ 'message' => 'from back end' ]);
  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_selectTargetsWithOffset', 'selectTargetsWithOffset');
```

Also tried
 - Going into admin-ajax.php and changing the response code from 400 to 420 to see if it would do anything. I did get some wierd error reflecting the change.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
// If no action is registered, return a Bad Request response.
if ( ! has_action( "wp_ajax_{$action}" ) ) {
    wp_die( 'Test', 420 );
}
```

- Changing '0' in arg1 of wp_die() to "Test" and visiting this url in the browser: http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php . I still see 0 rendered on the page (alone) at this address

Adding the following to the top of admin-ajax.php:

```
  ?>
    <script>
      console.log(`=====TEST=====`);
      var request = "<?php echo $_REQUEST ?>";
      console.log(request['action'], `=====request=====`);
    </script>
  <?php
```

When I try to trigger the ajax call in my admin area, I still get the 400 bad response console log only. However when I directly navigate to the URL, now I see the ===TEST=== statement and request is marked as undefined (as I would expect). I take this to mean something about how I call the ajax request is wrong.

Here is my HTML code for the button that does the call:

```
<button id="previousButton">Previous</button>
```

---

### In response to the simplified callback suggestion

Here is the console log:

```
=====jQuery success=====
VM13659:1 POST http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ VM13659:1
send @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:4
ajax @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:4
n.(anonymous function) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:4
(anonymous) @ options-general.php?page=fvc-settings:785
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:3
r.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:3
```

And here is the code:

```
function ajaxPost() {
  ?>
  <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#previousButton').click(function() {

        var postData = {
          action : 'selectTargetsWithOffset',
          data : {
            offsetMultiplier : 1,
            incrementSize : 10
          },
          success : function(response) {
            console.log(`=====jQuery success=====`);
          }
        };

        var handleResponse = function(response) {
          console.log(response, `=====response=====`);
        };

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, postData, handleResponse);
      }); 
    })
  </script>
  <?php
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'ajaxPost');


function selectTargetsWithOffsetcb() {
  print_r($_POST);
  die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_selectTargetsWithOffset', "selectTargetsWithOffsetcb");
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_selectTargetsWithOffset', "selectTargetsWithOffsetcb" );
```

There is no print_r() output on the page itself, it stays the same without any refreshing

It is worth noting again that the debug code `====TEST===` in admin-ajax.php failed to log. I think this indicates the request doesn't reach that file for some reason (since navigating to that file in browser does cause it to log to console)

---

Also tried this, but also a 400 error:

```
function ajaxPost() {
  ?>
  <script>    
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery(document).on("click","#previousButton", function() {
       jQuery.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>",
         data: {"action":"selectTargetsWithOffset","datas": {"name": "yourfields"}},
         type:"post",
         success: function(data) { alert(data); }
       })
     });    
    })
  </script>
  <?php
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'ajaxPost');
```

Comment: On your second AJAX code, try changing `"action"` to simply `action` (no double quotes): `action: "selectTargetsWithOffset"`.

Comment: @cabrerahector for objects, keys can be wrapped in single, double or no quotes. One major thing that I noticed, is no where do you declare `ajaxurl`.

Comment: The `ajaxurl` variable is already available in the admin section of WordPress so the OP doesn't need to declare it.

Comment: Ok, I have tried it but it didn't change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not declared callback functions in your plugin or function file.

Please add below code to your plugin or fn file and test it.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_selectTargetsWithOffset', "selectTargetsWithOffsetcb");
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_selectTargetsWithOffset', "selectTargetsWithOffsetcb" );

function selectTargetsWithOffsetcb()
{

    print_r($_POST);
    die();
}
```

Also update this js

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).on("click","#previousButton",function(){

jQuery.ajax({
url:"<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>",
data:{"action":"selectTargetsWithOffset","datas":{"name":"yourfields"}},
type:"post",
success:function(data){alert(data);}
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have posted my attempt in the original post

Comment: Did you see above? It's still not working unfortunately

Comment: How you are testing it? where you have written this code? can you provide any video url for it?

Comment: I save the modified file in my IDE and then force refresh the browser. As the site is in /var/html/www it proxies to localhost/